# How can I start a for-loop with 01 instead of 1?

Tags: php

How do I start a for-loop with `01` as opposed to `1`? I've tried the below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for ($i = 01; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    echo "<option value='$i'";
    if ($i == $post_response[expiremm]) { 
        echo " selected='selected'"; 
    }
    $month_text = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0, 0));
    echo ">$month_text</option>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really *start* an integer at 01, you will need to pad the value, probably using [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to prefix leading elements to a string:

```
$value = $i;
if ($i < 10) {
    $value = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Note that for different unit types you will obviously need to alter the desired `pad_length`.

Answer (score 5):

`01` is the octal number `1` (which is equivalent to the decimal `1` in this case). Since you want to *format* the output to have two digits for the number, consider using `printf`:

```
printf("<option value='%02d'", $i);
```

- `%` marks the start of a conversion
- `0` means "pad the string with zero"
- `2` means "the replacement should have a minimum length of 2"
- `d` means "the argument is an integer"

References:

- [PHP Manual: printf](http://php.net/printf)
- [PHP Manual: sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++) {
echo str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "<br/>"; }
```

it may help you..

Answer (score 0):

PHP will parse 01 as an integer, so it will become 1. You can't iterate on a string like '01' so you'll have to edit the value of $i later on in your code.

If you need a 01 later on, you could use padding.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0):

> for ($i = 01; $i <= 12; $i++) {

```
            $value = strlen($i);
            if($value==1){
                $k = "0".$i;
            }else
            {
                $k=$i;
            }
            echo "<option value='$k'";
            if ($i == $post_response[expiremm]) {
                echo " selected='selected'";
            }
            $month_text = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i + 1, 0, 0, 0));
            echo ">$month_text</option>";
        }
```

For loop can not start with 01 so you can do like this as shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = strlen($i);
        if($value==1){
            $k = "0".$i;
        }else
        {
            $k=$i;
        }
        echo "<option value='$k'";
        if ($i == $post_response[expiremm]) {
            echo " selected='selected'";
        }
        $month_text = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i + 1, 0, 0, 0));
        echo ">$month_text</option>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, if you want start counting not from 00 warp ($value +1) and then when it gets to the 10 it won't add 0 before

```
$count = 0;
$value = $count++;

echo str_pad(($value +1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```